# unwanted partial matches with Python replace

Tags: python

have a very simple function to replace from a dict :

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
```

I am calling this function in a pandas dataframe column. Could be a list or whatever else, it's just my example right now)
Here is an example of dataframe :

```
**root**
P1 
P2
P10
```

I want to obtain in the end something like :

```
**root**   **gen**
P1         bob
P2         jack
P10        mike
```

I am therefore using this little function with a dict

```
gen={"P1":"bob", "P2":"jack", "P10":"mike"}
df['gen']=df['root'].apply(lambda x : replace_all(x,gen))
```

That works without error message but I get partial matches.

```
**root**   **gen**
P1         bob
P2         jack
P10        bob0
```

It took P10 and replaced as P1, which sort of makes sense, but how to prevent this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str.replace` method is doing exactly what the docs say it should do... :-p

Try changing your `replace_all` function to this:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    return dic.get(text, text)
```

The `dict.get(key, default)` method returns `dict[key]` when `key in dict`, otherwise it returns `default`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `str.replace()` will replace a "substring" found anywhere in the string.

See: [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Options:

1. Use regular expressions to match and replace.
2. Match the whole string and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `text = text.replace(i, j)` with `text = dic[text]`

Comment: Won't work if `text not in dic`. Should use `dic.get(text, text)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since `replace` will find any portion of the string, consider this as an alternative:

```
>>> text = 'Hello P1 this is P2 with P10'
>>> d = {'P1': 'world', 'P2': 'peanut', 'P10': 'butter'}
>>> ' '.join(d.get(i, i) for i in text.split())
'Hello world this is peanut with butter'
```

Comment: This is a good approach if the OP really wants to replace whole words only, but I think he just wants to replace whole strings...